# how to put an array character into the equation?

Tags: c, arrays

i try to put 8 byte character into the equation causing a lot of error,what i'm supposed to do to make sure the equation can take the static value and produce output  in the 8 bytes.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <hidef.h> /* for EnableInterrupts macro */

#include "derivative.h" /* include peripheral declarations */

void voltage_measure(void);

void main(void) {

  voltage_measure();

}

void voltage_measure(void) {
   char Van1[8],VA;
   char Vbn[8],VB;
   char Vcn[8],VC;
   char AC[4],ac;
   char BC[4],bc;
   char AB[4],ab;    
   double Vab1,Vab2,Vbc1,Vbc2,Vac1,Vac2;
   double Vab[8],Vbc[8],Vac[8];

   Van1[0]=0xF0;   
   Van1[1]=0x00;
   Van1[2]=0x00;                                  
   Van1[3]=0x00;

   VA=0x000000F0;

   Vbn[0]=0x78;
   Vbn[1]=0x00;
   Vbn[2]=0x00;
   Vbn[3]=0x00;

   VB=0x78;

   Vcn[0]=0x3C;
   Vcn[1]=0x00;
   Vcn[2]=0x00;
   Vcn[3]=0x00;

   VC=0x3C;

   AB[0]=0xB4;
   AB[1]=0x00;

   ab=0xB4;

   AC[0]=0x2D;
   AC[1]=0x00;

   ac=0x2D;

   BC[0]=0x5A;
   BC[1]=0x00;

   bc=0x5A;
   Vab1=(VB*sin(ab))*(VB*sin(ab))  ;
   Vab2=(VA+(VB*cos(ab)))*(VA+(VB*cos(ab)));
   Vab[4]=sqrt(Vab1+Vab2);

   Vbc1=(VC*sin(bc))*(VC*sin(bc));
   Vbc2=(VB+(VC*cos(bc)))*(VB+(VC*cos(bc))) ;
   Vbc[4]=sqrt(Vbc1+Vbc2);

   Vac1=(VC*sin(ac))*(VC*sin(ac));
   Vac2=(VA+(VC*cos(ac)))*(VA+(VC*cos(ac)));
   Vac[4]=sqrt(Vac1+Vac2);
}
```

Comment: You might want to expand on your question a little...

Comment: -1 until more information provided

Comment: First off, `main()` should not return `void`. It should return `int`. Any compiler that lets your `main()` return `void` is wrong.

Comment: @Chris: it may be wrong, but it's not uncommon in embedded software. Some compilers don't even require there to be a main function at all!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have understood as yet,

1. you want to do arithmetic with double precision that has several parameters

   - you would like to store the parameters in `char` variables (maybe to save on space?)
   - I don't know why you try to write `VA=0x000000F0;` when its a `char` (1 byte) variable
   - the `static value` you refer are probably the constants `VA` etc
   - It might be useful to have all these working in the arithmetic at `double` precision
   - when you use the `sin` and `sqrt` kind of functions, they will work at `double` anyways
   - you do not have a `main` function listed here;
   - it would be there in your actual file (that compiles this code)
   - so, i am also assuming you have things like `math.h` included
     and the math library on the compile command
   - that is, you do get the binary compiled without errors

maybe you can elaborate the problem you are facing a little more?

---

1. Update from comment 1.
   When you say, "character with 8 byte array" -- are you trying to create a `double` with an 8 `char` array?

   - Update from comment 2.
     If your answer is in `double`, you can catch it in a `double` variable.
     A `double` is already 8-bytes (on most platforms).
     Is there a special reason to get it into a `char` array or a byte array?
   - Update from comment 3.
     The link error implies you did include a math library for the linking.
     The header just gives function prototypes for compilation.
     With `gcc`, it would be `-lm` on the command line.
   - Update from comment 4.
     To convert a `double` to an integer value check this page,
     [**How can I convert a floating-point value to an integer in C?**](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html)

Comment: actually in this programming i try to created character with 8 byte array,and than the value Va is only the combination of the array,so what can i do so that the char value can be put into the equation.

Comment: from the calculation the answer must be in double.so i need to created a double with an 8 char array.is that possible..

Comment: @kiki: double VA = Van[0] + (Van[1] * pow(2, 8)) + (Van[2] * pow(2,16)) + (Van[3] * pow(2,24)) ...;

Comment: i also do not know what the special reason..i just been asked to do it so.i was facing the link error when i try to compile..it say that "sin"is undefined but i already include the math.h

Comment: do you know ow to assign values to a UINT8 variable?

Answer (score 0):

Is the trouble that plain `char` on your machine is signed, so numbers such as 0xF0 are treated as -16 instead of +240?  Did you know that on some machines, this is what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your link error you mentioned in the comments: including math.h is not enough, you have to tell the linker to add the library as well. Try adding "-lm" in your command line.